# Adding own functionality into iOS library

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, object, subclassing

I am using a a library which has quite complicated inherited structure (it consists of a couple of classes, inherited e.g. `UITableViewController`, `UIView`, `UITableViewCell` and others, where some of the classes are used to create custom objects.

I need to add some functionality (to be precise, to implement tap gesture recognizers). The easy solutions is to put a few lines of code into some of the classes of the library.
Generally, I like to have my code separated from libraries code. Is it possible somehow "override" these classes without rewriting them, or to add some extension?

Or the only idea is to write overrides of all the classes generating own classes and tons of useless code?

Or simply add own code to the library?

**Additions:**
It seems, that categories are right direction, but not particularly, what I want. Here's what I want exactly:
I have a in `Class1`:

```
- (void)someMethod {
doThis;
}
```

And without subclassing // editing the class I would like to transform this to:

```
- (void)someMethod {
doThis;
andThisToo;
}
```

Categories add other methods to a class, while I need to add some functionality in already existing method.

Comment: Class categories could work.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, thank you! Good and elegant solution, this is what I was asking for!

Comment: Is it good idea to make a pull request for author of such library?

Comment: If you want the author to use your changes it's probably better to just add this functionality directly in the classes of the library. If this is a customization that you think will only ever be used by you then you shouldn't touch the library directly. Use categories instead.

Comment: CrimsonChris, I added some further explanations. Seems that categories are close, but not what I'm particularly looking for. Am I right, there are only two solutions now: either subclass each class or add functionality to the library?

Comment: What you are asking for requires some deep magic. Look into method swizzling, it is scary but powerful.

Comment: Well, I checked how it works, but decided to go with editing library's code and make a pull request. The library I'm talking about is just mimics standard iOS calendar but has no gesture recognizers, so, user cannot interact with the views. But thanx a lot for `method swizzling`, it is good to know that another solution exists =) 

PS I tried to use KISS method: in my opinion, just adding a few lines to a library is easier than making such things as method swizzling. It just requires more time and, again, I consider touch recognizers to be there by default.

Comment: Have you considered just placing transparent buttons over the calendar?

Comment: Not. Why should I do so, if I can just put UIGestureRecognizer code into view creation process?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the decorator pattern.

> The decorator pattern is used to extend or alter the functionality of
>   objects at run- time by wrapping them in an object of a decorator
>   class. This provides a flexible alternative to using inheritance to
>   modify behaviour.

Since the example you give is pretty sketchy, I can't provide a code example, but check out Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

**EDIT**

I thought about what you gave and here would be an example of a decorator:

```
@interface Decorator
@property (strong, nonatomic) id decoratedObject;
- (void)someMethod;
@end

@implementation Decorator
- (void)someMethod {
    [self.decoratedObject doThis];
    [self andDoThisToo];
}

@end
```

Comment: Its a good point, but as already discussed, I need to add some functionality to the already existing method. According to this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns , I can use either Categories or Delegates. Neither of these satisfies me, so I end up with changing library's code.

Comment: concerning your edit: in my particular case the method should be modified on an object which is far away from "my" classes and is being placed deeply in library's hierarchy. So, If I go with this approach, I need to change (or write categories to) other classes in the library, which is not that fast.

Comment: As long as the Decorator satisfies the same interface as the decorated object, it doesn't matter how far away, or deep the object is in the library. And the Decorator can satisfy that interface just by forwarding all unmodified calls to the decorated object. Of course you do have to be able to get to the object you want to decorate, but if you can't even do that, then maybe you should rethink your design. That said, if the idea doesn't work, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Daniel, you're totally right, but the point is that it is not my architecture and the last thing I would like to do (and actually, I've done it this way) is to change it, as you said. Method Swizzling was the exact thing I was asking about, but it will only overcomplicate the things.Anyway, thanx for the response.    
Maybe, the actual point here is that the library I'm using is supplied only as "example" project, but not as a library, so it requires modifications and "surgical intervention" by design